# How to perform partial search and return the full word with Regex.Match?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to handle my exceptions based on regular expressions. To do this, all my constraints start the same way. (CCC_TABLE_COLUMN_TYPECONSTRAINT)

Ex:

CCC_USER_NAME_UNIQUE

CCC_BOOKS_TITLE_UNIQUE.

I'm not able to return the entire string.

```
try
{
      await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}catch(Exception ex)
{
      regex = new Regex("CCC");
      var reg1 = regex.Match(ex.toString());         
}
```

In reg1 only "CCC" is returned. How do I return the entire constraint name?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend adding a [tag:regex] tag for a question about regexes, to attract the best expertise, and I'd suggest removing the [tag:asp.net], as this question is unrelated to that subject area. Can I also ask for clarification of the question by adding an example of what `exception` contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include matching all the parts

```
CCC_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+
```

Assuming you are only using upper case letters in the names.  If not replace the `[A-Z]` with an expression that would match.

Comment: How do I do with CCC_STATE.COUNTRY_COUNTRYID_FK?

Comment: Just include period like `CCC_[A-Z.]+_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+`